# xsd.exe: resolving XSD conflict

Tags: .net, xml, exchangewebservices

I am trying to combine the Exchange autodiscovery XSDs at this location:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee160637(v=exchg.80).aspx

Basically, it's one "Request" XSD and three "Response XSDs". The three response XSDs define different responses (a correct response, an error response, and a redirect response), so each file contains a class somewhat like this:

```
<Autodiscover>
 <Request>
   ...
 </Request>
</Autodiscover>

<Autodiscover>
<Response>
   ...good response...
</Response>
</Autodiscover>

<Autodiscover>
<Response>
   ...error response...
</Response>
</Autodiscover>

<Autodiscover>
<Response>
   ...redirect response...
</Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

The problem is that the "response" XSDs obviously have the same name so they conflict once I generate XSDs and include them in the project (C# project). What is the best practive for handling this situation, hopefully with minimum or no modification to the original XSDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put each generated class into its own namespace, and then (optionally) create an alias for each one.

Comment: Thank you. That was my fallback, but architecturally (from the point of view of my application) it is quite ugly. It's not what namespaces are for. :(